# Query a specific column in the database

Tags: java, database, listview

I have 2 activities. The first one displays a list of data obtained from the MySQL table. By clicking on a list item, the next activity on which information about the pressed item will be displayed will be opened. But for this I need to create a new database query and get only the column that I passed as the "id" from listview

MainAcitvity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

ListView listView;
DataBase dataBase;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
FloatingActionButton fabMain;
MySimpleAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
Cursor cursor;
Task taskClass;

TextView tvTitleItemList, tvTextItemList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fabMain = findViewById(R.id.fab_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    tvTitleItemList = findViewById(R.id.tv_title_item_list);
    tvTextItemList = findViewById(R.id.tv_text_item_list);



    dataBase = new DataBase(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();


    //next activity and add in database
    fabMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    //get
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(dataBase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    simpleCursorAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);






   //delete
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskActivity.class );
            String value = simpleCursorAdapter.id;
            intent.putExtra("id", value);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();



    simpleCursorAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

}
```

activity in which you need to re-create a database query by id

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvTitleActivityTask, tvTextActivityTask;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);

        tvTitleActivityTask = findViewById(R.id.tv_title_activity_task);
        tvTextActivityTask = findViewById(R.id.tv_text_activity_task);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getExtras();

        String valueId = intent.getStringExtra("id");



    }
}
```

Comment: What the problem to use your valueId to request the data...? And in general for you it would be better to start using/learning room instead of old school sqlite. It's more understandable for new developers and you will not have such questions. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room enjoy

Comment: @Евгений I would like to know which of the 7 request parameters to pass id

Comment: Of course you don't. Because you just know how to copy and paste. That's why you have no clue what's going on here.(4th parameter for your Id, but it will not work just after you replace null to id) Here is an info how it's work https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder but still i strongly recommend to start using room persistence.